# How to return false to main function if it is from inside Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveRecord function?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I have created a javascript function to do some validation in another entity. The validation is working but I am trying to return false to the main function from inside function, I am new in dynamics 365 framework and in javascript

the code:

```
function SubmitAction(executionContext) {
var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
var userSettings = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings;
var languageCode = userSettings.languageId;
var isAirportValis = ValidateAirportCountry(executionContext);
var IsConfidential=formContext.getAttribute("alfa_confidentialguest").getValue();
var a = true;

//Edit by Abdallah To get the package Type so we can get the package type
var lookupItem = formContext.getAttribute("alfa_member").getValue()[0].id;
var theTotalMembersTravling = formContext.getAttribute("alfa_numberofdependent").getValue();
var remainFlightCredit;

debugger;
Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveRecord("contact",lookupItem, "?$select=new_remainstravelcredit").then(
     function employessPackage(result) {
        var new_remainstravelcredit = result["new_remainstravelcredit"];
        if(new_remainstravelcredit !== null){
        if(new_remainstravelcredit > 0)
        {
            remainFlightCredit = new_remainstravelcredit;
            console.log(remainFlightCredit+" This not inside any if condition");

                    var newRemain = (parseInt(remainFlightCredit)) - (parseInt(theTotalMembersTravling));
                    console.log(newRemain+ " This in the remain if condition");
                    var entity = {};
                    entity.new_remainstravelcredit = newRemain.toString();
                    Xrm.WebApi.online.updateRecord("contact",lookupItem, entity).then(
                    function success(result) {
                        var updatedEntityId = result.id;
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message +" This error is occuring from retriveing the altanfeethi emplyees packgae");
                    }
                );
        } if(new_remainstravelcredit <= 0)
        {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("You have exceeds the travel credit");
            return false;
          //  throw Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("You have exceeds the travel credit");

        } 
    }
    },
    function(error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    }
);



if (!isAirportValis) {
    return false;
}
//var isAttachemntValid = ValidateAttachments(formContext);
//if (!isAttachemntValid) {
//    return false;
//}

var hasTravellers = ValidateTravellers(formContext)
if (!hasTravellers && !IsConfidential) {
    var userSettings = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings;
    var languageCode = userSettings.languageId;
    if (languageCode == "1033") {
        alert(Messages.FlightMemberCountValidation1033);
    }
    else {
        alert(Messages.FlightMemberCountValidation1025);
    }
    return false;
}


var isGuestValid = isValidGuest(formContext);
var isPaymentValid = false;
var guestPaymentType = formContext.getAttribute('alfa_guestpaymenttype').getValue();
var addedGuestServices = formContext.getControl('guestservices').getGrid().getTotalRecordCount();
if (!isGuestValid) {

    var membershipType = GetMembershipType();
    if (membershipType != MembershipTypeEnum.Corportate) // Individual
    {
        formContext.getControl('alfa_guestpaymenttype').setVisible(true);
        formContext.getAttribute('alfa_guestpaymenttype').setRequiredLevel('required');

        if (!guestPaymentType) {
            if (languageCode == "1033")
                alert(Messages.IndividualGuestSub1033);
            else alert(Messages.IndividualGuestSub1025);
            formContext.getControl('alfa_guestpaymenttype').setFocus();
            return false;
        }
        else if (guestPaymentType == GuestPaymentTypeEnum.BuyPackage) {
            if (addedGuestServices == 0) {
                if (languageCode == "1033")
                    alert(Messages.AddGuestService1033);
                else alert(Messages.AddGuestService1025);
                formContext.getControl('guestservices').setFocus();
                return false;
            }
            else isPaymentValid = true;
        }
        else if (guestPaymentType == GuestPaymentTypeEnum.PayForAdded)
            isPaymentValid = true;
    }
    else  // Corp
    {
        formContext.getControl('alfa_guestpaymenttype').setVisible(false);
        //var addedGuestServices = formContext.getControl('guestservices').getGrid().getTotalRecordCount();
        // if (addedGuestServices == 0) {
        if (languageCode == "1033")
            alert(Messages.AddGuestService1033);
        else alert(Messages.AddGuestService1025);
        formContext.getControl('guestservices').setFocus();
        return false;
        // }
        //else isPaymentValid = true;
    }
    if (isPaymentValid) {
        formContext.getAttribute('alfa_requirepayment').setValue(true);
        formContext.getAttribute('alfa_issubmitted').setValue(true);
        formContext.data.save();
    }

}

else {
    formContext.getAttribute('alfa_requirepayment').setValue(addedGuestServices > 0);
    formContext.getControl('alfa_guestpaymenttype').setVisible(false);
    formContext.getAttribute('alfa_guestpaymenttype').setRequiredLevel('none');     
    formContext.getAttribute('alfa_issubmitted').setValue(true);
    formContext.data.save();
 }


}
```

In the line where the if condition checking "if(new_remainstravelcredit <= 0)"
I want to return false from the main function "SubmitAction" but it does not work as when it goes inside the if condition if(new_remainstravelcredit <= 0) it then resume with the main function implementation. Any suggestions on how can I enforce to return false and exit the SumbitAction function from the inner function emploessPackage

Comment: you can't return `false` "to" the main functions since `Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveRecord` returns a Promise - you would write your code using promise methods as you are already doing - anything that relies on values inside the promise chain needs to be done inside the promise chain, or in a new `.then` chained to the current chain

Comment: Can you have suggestion how can I modified it to be able to return false to the main function, is it possible to make xrm.webapi in different function where this function will return false in case it comes inside the if condition? @Bravo

Comment: you can't return a value synchronously based on an asynchronous result - you'll need to use asynchronous methods, like callbacks, promises etc, to achieve your goal - would have to see how `SubmitAction` is being used to be of any help to you (i.e. what is calling it, what does it do with the result, etc)

Comment: It's a long function, anyhow i updated the code i put the full function @Bravo

Comment: You should use `async`/`await` (with `try`/`catch`)for your Promises in that case, instead of `.then`/`.catch`, will make the code easier to write

Comment: Can you show me how @Bravo the async and await

Comment: Not with your code, way too much code for me ... but [here's a guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

Answer (score 0):

```
//using Promise

function getTeams() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("...").then(
            function success(result) {
               // code

                // return list
                resolve(listTeam);
            },
            function (error) {
                reject(error.message);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).